# How to force glob library to read over the files in alfabetical order for each name file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, glob

I have this little function that apply a regex to a set of documents over a directory:

```
def retrive(directory, a_regex):
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            important_stuff = re.findall(a_regex, file.read(), re.S)
            my_list = [tuple([j.split()[0] for j in i]) for i in important_stuff]
            # print my_list # old line
            print str(my_list).strip('[]') + filename.split('/')[-1]


lists_per_file = retrive(directory,regex_)
```

How can I "guarantee" or "force" `retrive` function to do its work in an alphabetical aproach (i.e. to apply the regex in alfabetical order for each file name). Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the glob:

```
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.txt'))):
```